# Alternative to glMultiDrawArrays when using uniform stride?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, opengl-3

**Background**: I am developing an application that essentially draws a huge 3D graph of nodes and edges. The nodes are drawn as instanced cubes while the edges are drawn with `GL_LINE` and expanded with a geometry shader into 3D volumetric "lines" made of triangle strips. Currently, I am performing this expansion every time I redraw the edges. However, as my graph is entirely static (nodes can not move and thus neither can the edges), I figure that I only need to expand the `GL_LINE` definitions into triangle strips once, capture the expanded vertices into a buffer (using Tranform Feedback), and then from that point on draw the edges using those captured vertices with `glMutliDrawArrays` using a primitive type of `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP`.

**Question:** All of these volumetric lines I am drawing contain 10 vertices. However, `glMultiDrawArrays` requires an array of starting indices and count sizes that essentially describe the start point and count (in elements) of each primitive. As none of my primitives vary in size, I would be making an seemingly unnecessary list of starting indices & counts. Is there any functionality OpenGL provides that would allow me to simply specify a stride (in elements) at which primitive restart would occur?

Comment: +1 for explaining why you need it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such function, but for your needs, you don't need one. Transform feedback *cannot* output triangle strips. It outputs only *basic* primitives: individual points, lines, or triangles. That's why [`glBeginTransformFeedback`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glBeginTransformFeedback) only takes `GL_POINTS`, `GL_LINES`, or `GL_TRIANGLES`.

All you have to do is render all of your edges at once, collect the results into a single buffer via feedback, and later render the entire thing with a single call to `glDrawArrays`.

Comment: What if I do the following: Render the line endpoints using `glDrawTransformFeedback` with a mode of `GL_POINTS`, set the `out` layout qualifier in my geometry shader to points, and capture the volumetric line vertices using a buffer bound to target `GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER`. Then, rebind that buffer to target GL_ARRAY_BUFFER and call  glMultiDrawArrays using a mode of `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP` to render the captured geometry. Would this work?

Comment: @SirDigbyChickenCaesar: I don't know how that would work. Your shader would effectively have to use point writing to output a strip of triangles. Somehow. And I don't know why you insist on this to begin with; just *render the triangle list*. It's really that simple. Why do you *need* strips so badly?

Comment: I have to output points from the geometry shader in order to use output streams though correct? So to accomplish what I want, I would need to output all pertinent data of the vertices to different streams (one for normal, one for position, etc.. ) regardless of what primitive I will use in the next drawing routine. As for why I'm using triangle strips, it is solely to save overhead. Although, I'm not sure the memory saved will be negligible or not so I will probably start with rendering triangles.

Comment: @SirDigbyChickenCaesar: You do know that you can output more than one value to the same stream, right? Multi-stream output is for outputting values at different *frequencies*. Since all you're outputting this stuff for is to just render it later, there's no point in that. One position has one normal, one texture coordinate, etc. So it should all go to the same stream.

Comment: Yeah, I JUST figured that out looking through the OpenGL wiki. Thanks for the heads up!